# How to scale out a NServiceBus publisher

Tags: .net, nservicebus, publish-subscribe

I know there should not be multiple publishers publishing the same event.
But how should I scale out a subscriber that publishes an event after it processed the event it is subscribed to? Scaling this out will result in multiple publishers publishing the same event.

When searching on google I get conflicting answers. One says I should use send instead of publish and another source says just to use a shared subscription storage.

I would probably go with a shared subscription storage but I'm not sure if this will work properly.

Comment: So the subscriber is publishing the same event it just processed?  Is that in order to handle more load?

Comment: No, for example it could be billing which is subscribed to OrderPlaced and is publishing an event PaymentDetailsEmailed (after it processed OrderPlaced).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading this correctly I would leverage the [Distributor](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/scalability-and-ha/distributor/) to scale the Subscribers out.  If you are using 3.0, this would include adding another node and a small amount of config.  If you are using 2.x, this involves a bit more setup including another endpoint.  There are some [visuals on the site](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/publish-subscribe/).

Comment: Scaling out the subscriber is not the issue.
When I would use the distributor to scale out the subscribers I will also get multiple publishers publishing the same event. How should I handle multiple publishers publishing the same event.

Comment: With the Distributor the work is split, so each publisher will be publishing a different set of events.  They would share subscription storage so that all subscribers receive messages regardless of which endpoint did the publishing.

Comment: So the subscription storage can be shared between different instances of the same event publisher and will not result into conflicts between them?

Comment: Yes, its just the list of subscribers.  The conflicts are avoiding my sharding the data that goes to each one via the Distributor.